# Receive emit from a room socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to send data through a room. When I login, I join the socket to a room named from variable username

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
   var addedUser = false;
   socket.on('login', function (data) {
      if (addedUser) return;
      // we store the username in the socket session for this client
        socket.username = data.username;
        addedUser = true;
        socket.join(result.username, function (err) {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
          } else {
            console.log("Success joined room " + data.username);
          }
        });
        message = {
          success: true,
          message: "Successfully logged in",
          data: result,
          socket_id: socket.id
        };
      //Emit Value
      socket.emit('login result', message);
   }
});
```

I get the log `Success joined room fadel`

Then I send data from my client, using emit like this

```
socket.on('request', function (data) {
  console.log(data);
  io.sockets.in(data.username).emit('price', {
    username: data.username,
    price: data.price
  });
```

I get the log `{ id: 'fadel', price: '123' }`

Then I try to get the broadcast using this

```
socket.on('price', function(data){
  console.log(data);
});
```

I cannot seem to get any data at all. But when I try this normal emit (without room), I can get the data

```
io.emit('price', {
    price: data.price
});
```

How do I get the broadcast from room on client side? Do I need anything else than `socket.on('price', function(data){});` ?

I'm using socket.io v 1.7.3

Comment: socket.on('price', function(data){}); should be inside the io.on('connection function', function(data){});

Comment: but it is on my client js, on the html.